# Can't Start Fail2Ban

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, services, fail2ban

Lately I got 3 emails from Fail2Ban

- The jail nginx-http-auth has been stopped.
- The jail nginx-badbots has been stopped.
- The jail ssh has been stopped.

Then I start SSH into my VM, this is the log

```
└── tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log
2019-09-17 21:06:06,201 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 49.73.61.65
2019-09-17 21:06:06,208 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 178.128.104.155
2019-09-17 21:06:06,215 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 139.59.13.51
2019-09-17 21:06:06,221 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 139.59.84.111
2019-09-17 21:06:06,227 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 138.197.221.114
2019-09-17 21:06:06,232 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 49.88.112.114
2019-09-17 21:06:06,241 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j fail2ban-ssh
iptables -F fail2ban-ssh
iptables -X fail2ban-ssh returned 100
2019-09-17 21:07:06,335 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' stopped
```

Then I tried to stop and start

```
service fail2ban stop
service fail2ban start
```

I kept getting

```
└── service fail2ban stop                                                                                                                                       
 * Stopping authentication failure monitor fail2ban                                                                                                      [ OK ] 
└── service fail2ban start                                                                                                                               
 * Starting authentication failure monitor fail2ban                                                         * Socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock is present
```

How do I fix this further ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `fail2ban-client reload` and then restart your service.